# Can I customize the shell command line prompt?

Tags: customization, command-line

Is there a way to customize the command line prompt (e.g., colorize it) for `MathKernel` when it runs as a shell command (in general, but specifically on OS X)?

Comment: What kind of customizations would you like? And are you using zsh or bash?

Comment: @M.R.: Just color would be enough (different for in and out preferably); bash.